# detect a wrong paragraph in a text by the minimum steps of verification

Tags: probability, proof-verification, context-free-grammar

You have a text 80.000 word long and you know there is a wrong paragraph (just one).  then what the minimum of steps i should take to reach the max probability i find it?

Comment: I assume you are comparing your document to an "original". The max probability of finding the wrong paragraph is 1 if you compare the two texts letter by letter, which is $O(n)$ steps.

Comment: thanks at first but  if i compare the two texts letter by letter the number of steps is at max!

Comment: yes, but that is the cost of requiring max probability of finding the wrong paragraph. If you are willing to lower that probability then sure you can do better than looking at all the data, but your question states that you want max probability. Max probability is indeed 1, and can be achieved only by looking a all the data.